# sudo yum install oracle (-instantclient,-instantclient-basic,etc) not working

Tags: oracle, yum, installation

Specifically I would like to know what the package name is for the `yum` package for Oracle Instant Client. I've [tried some that Google seemed to like](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ie=UTF-8#hl=en&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=yum%20install%20oracle%20instant%20client&oq=&gs_l=&pbx=1&fp=b4c92a2d29177826&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.,cf.osb&biw=1280&bih=612), such as `oracle`, `oracle-instantclient-basic`, `oracle-instantclient-devel`, etc.

Second, how can I search available `yum` packages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you perhaps missing the step where he downloads the RPMs from Oracle and places them into his own internal Yum repository?

> I [downloaded](http://www.oracle.com/technology/software/tech/oci/instantclient/htdocs/linuxx86_64soft.html) the instant client RPMs from Oracle to my local private yum repo that I use for in-house packages. Doesn't everyone have one of those? Then all ya gotta do is...

You can list available packages with `yum list <search glob>` or search the metadata with `yum search <search glob>`

Examples:

`yum search mozilla`
`yum list firef*`

See also: [yum man page](http://linux.die.net/man/8/yum)